# How to fetch selected value from drop down list in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to fetch value of drop down list into label by jQuery.
I was trying with this code

```
$("#ddl").click(function () {

       var val = $("#ddl").val(); 
       $("#DDLValue").val(val);

});
```

Comment: If you show the HTML as well, it would be a lot easier to answer, and you did of course wrap that jQuery code in document.ready ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$("#ddl").change(function () {

       var val = $(this).val(); 
       $("#DDLValue").html(val);

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Labels don't have a value attribute. Use their innerHTML, and bind it to the `change` event:

```
$("#ddl").on('change',function () {
    $("#DDLValue").html($(this).val());
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VUQFB/

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('#ddl').change(function() {
        alert($(this).val());
  });
```

use [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) function

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#ddl').change(function(){
     $("#DDLValue").html($(this).val());
});
});
```

Update ..if you want the selected text and not the value ,use

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ddl').change(function(){
         $("#DDLValue").html($(this).find('option:selected').text());
    });
    });
```

OR If your select box is generated dynamically,Use `delegate`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').delegate('#ddl','change',function(){
        //stuff here
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Note: html element label does not have a value attribute therefore use `.html()` or `.text()`.

**JQuery code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#ddl').change(function () {
    $('#DDLValue').text($(this).val());
   });
});
```

**Html code**

```
<select id="ddl" name="ddl">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
</select>​
<label id="DDLValue"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try code :

```
$("#ddl").change(function(){
             $('#DDLValue').val( $("#ddl option:selected").text() );
        });
```